# Add image in the input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a following scenario but i dont know how to add the text followed by image and text followed by image and so on. Please refer the image below and that is an input text with values

[image: Text]

How do i  achieve this using jquery and css?

If possible show it in js fiddle

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: `<input type="text">` only supports text content, not images. Any implementations that appear to support inline images are not actually `<input>`s but a `<div>` or other container element styled to look like one.

Comment: yo, See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LqVNM/6/ and this reply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420967/making-image-positioned-on-textbox-clickable-in-case-of-ipad-creating-html5-sea `:)`

Comment: can you please show me how to achieve this using div?

Comment: For a single text is fine, but I am having multiple text. As shown above, Acme processing followed by image and Universal studios followed by image and X folloed by image and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HTML:
<input type="text" name="whatever" id="funkystyling" />

CSS:
#funkystyling {
    background: white url(/path/to/icon.png) right no-repeat;
    padding-right: 17px;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/markom/5Ayx7/